# Implement listview with custom background

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i know about how to implement listview & customizing items also. But i'm confused on how to implement list shown below.

I'm able to implement listview with custom header & its sub items. For eg

```
1-jan-14
------------------
item1
item2
item3

2-jan-14
------------------
item2
item3

3-feb-14
------------------
item4
```

Now in this i want to customize few background as well as item look like `1-jan-14` items should show with one group, `2-jan-14` should come in separate group but overall all the elements will be part of single listview.

Reference image is like this

[image]

Comment: We are talking about **ExpandableListView**, right?

Comment: No, i dont want it to be expandableListview, a simple listview is fair enough. The gray color is simple listview & all these white color are items

Comment: I'd see an `ExpandableListView` more fit for the task. In which case you want to set the **group** background (then inherited by the **children**, if not differently specified).

Comment: At this moment, i want to show it with normal listview. User should feel like we have different items in different date. Thats all. Do you have any example code please?

Answer (score 0):

Either you set the backround of the parent layout or of the layout itself like:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a group of, for eg:

```
1-jan-14
------------------
item1
item2
item3
```

as a single row in the listview to which you can set different backgrounds (for different rows).

Also If you want the rows spaced like in the drawing you should use

```
android:dividerHeight="5dp"
android:divider="@null"
```

in the layout of the listview.